# .vbp could not be loaded and NOT in notepad neither

Tags: vb6

As of yesterday, my vbp file refuses to open '.vbp could not be loaded'. If i try to open the individual forms, some of them work (open in vb6), some of them produce error .log file with two class errors : Class TabDlg.SSTab of control mstTabArticles was not a loaded control class. Line 3672: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control dtpTicketDate was not a loaded control class.

I cannot open the vbp in notepad neither (=empty) and in wordpad i only get small squares...

Any help please?

Comment: Do you have any kind of source control or backup? Then you could diff the project with it's previous version to see if anything has changed.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized as I don't see this being of use to anyone else.

Comment: I don't think this *is* localised. I have experienced this same issue myself. Although the resolution is to restore from a previous backed up version it might be useful just to know *that*

Answer (score 3):

Your `.vbp` file is corrupt. You will either need to restore from your backup or source control (you do have both of those don't you?).
Failing that, you will need to recreate the project file from scratch and readd each of the forms. You'll need to figure out what controls and references were loaded though.

As for the errors when loading the form files, this is normal as the controls have not been added to the project.

Comment: Thanks for the help Deanna ! That's what I was afraid of.. :( unfortunately no backup or source control - luckily not such a huge project, so should not take thàt long to recreate.. but nevertheless, important lesson learned... :)

Comment: If your vbp file is really large, so that you really want to find ways to rescue it, try opening it with a hex editor.  Most of the text won't be corrupt, so you can copy and paste large pieces of it into a new file.  Save you a lot of work placing controls and setting properties.  (Oops, I already said that!  Well, I expanded a bit here so I'll leave it in.)

Comment: @BobRodes Control placement and code is in the `.frm` files. The `.vbp` file only contains a list of forms and modules, references and some project details. Further more, if you want to expand on your answer, you can with the "edit" link underneath it.

Comment: Duh my bad.  I knew that, of course; guess vb6 skills are getting a bit rusty.  Thanks for the correction, Deanna.  Also, I was saying that I forgot that I had answered this earlier, but had expanded on my earlier answer so I'd leave it in.  Anyway, you're quite right.  All you have to do is create a new vbp file and add all the forms back in.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility is to open your file with a hex editor.  You may be able to rescue a good deal of the text from the corrupt file and copy it to a new one.

Comment: Notepad will already show any text that is in the file. A hex editor won;t show anything extra bar what the corrupt data is.

Comment: I suppose that's right, although I haven't tested it and haven't a desire to.  :)